# Multi dimensional 3d arrary php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, 3d, calculation

```
$sql = "
SELECT a.*
     , b.*
     , c.* 
  FROM aasms_station a
  LEFT 
  JOIN aasms_sector b
    ON b.station_id = a.station_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN aasms_technology c
    ON c.sector = b.sector_id 
   AND a.station_id = c.station_id 
 WHERE a.station_id = 10 
   AND a.user_id = 333
";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop

         $array = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                $sectors  = $row['sector'];
                $technologies = $row['tech_id'];

                $array['station_id'] = $row['station_id'];
                $array['applicant_name'] = $row['applicant_name'];
                $array['address'] = $row['address'];
                $array['telno'] = $row['telno'];
                $array['faxno'] = $row['faxno'];
                $array['email'] = $row['email'];
                $array['site_name'] = $row['site_name'];
                $array['location_address'] = $row['location_address'];
                $array['latitude'] = $row['latitude'];
                $array['longtitude'] = $row['longtitude'];
                $array['installationtype'] = $row['installationtype'];
                $array['colocation'] = $row['colocation'];
                $array['environmenttype'] = $row['environmenttype'];
                $array['natureofservice'] = $row['natureofservice'];
                $array['operation_date'] = $row['operation_date'];
                $array['operation_hours'] = $row['operation_hours'];
                $array['consultationtype'] = $row['consultationtype'];
                $array[$sectors]['sector_id'] = $row['sector_id'];
                $array[$sectors]['sector'] = $row['sector'];                        
                $array[$sectors]['azimuth'] = $row['azimuth'];                      

                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['tech_id'] = $row['tech_id'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['height_antenna'] = $row['height'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['height_roof'] = $row['height_roof'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['distance_adjacent'] = $row['distance'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['height_adjacent'] = $row['adj_height'];                    
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['radius'] = $row['radius'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['dimension'] = $row['dimension'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['installationtype'] = $row['installationtype'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['antennaonedge'] = $row['antennaonedge'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['exclusionarea'] = $row['exclusionarea'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['specify_area'] = $row['specify_area'];                 
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['operator'] = $row['operator'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['sector_id'] = $row['sector_id'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['technology'] = $row['technology'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['frequency'] = min(explode(",", $row['frequency'])));
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['electricaltilt'] = $row['electricaltilt'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['mechanicaltilt'] = $row['mechanicaltilt'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['antennagain'] = $row['antennagain'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['v_beamwidth'] = $row['v_beamwidth'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['h_beamwidth'] = $row['h_beamwidth'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['eirp'] = $row['eirp'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['asl'] = $row['asl'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['rooftop'] = $row['rooftop'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['adjacent_building'] = $row['adj_building'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['tilt'] = $row['electricaltilt'] + $row['mechanicaltilt'];
                $array[$sectors][$technologies]['vertical_beamwidth'] = $row['v_beamwidth'] + $row['h_beamwidth'];
                if ($row['specify_area'] == 'Circular'){
                    $array[$sectors][$technologies]['a'] = $row['radius'];
                }
                else if ($row['specify_area'] == 'Rectangular')
                    {
                    $array[$sectors][$technologies]['a'] = $row['dimension'];
                }



            }
            echo "<b>Sector ID" . $array[$sectors]['sector'] . "</b>";
                echo "<b>Sector ID" . count($array[$sectors]['sector']) . "</b>";

            echo '<pre>',print_r($array),'</pre>';
```

I need to display the values in 3d array and perform calculation for each technology per sector to determine feasible or not.

Comment: what do you mean with _3d array_ ?

Comment: It's exceptionally rare to want all columns from all tables